# Can I 'glue and screw' 1/2" and 3/8" plywood sheets to substitute for 7/8"?

Tags: subfloor, plywood

Replacing damaged parts of a plank floor that is 7/8" thick. Need a level surface to lay another 1/2" plywood subfloor layer. Can I 'glue and screw' a two thinner pieces of plywood (1/2" and 3/8"), or do I need to source 7/8" plywood? I would use pl premium and screws for compression between the layers. My other idea was to add 1/8" hardboard strips on top of the joists in those sections and just using 3/4" instead. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on how far the plywood is spanning. How far apart are the floor joists.?

Comment: Right. Forgot to mention the joists are 16" OC

Comment: I'd use 3/4" for strength on top of 1/8" shims on the joists. (In theory, your 1/2+3/8=7/8, but I'm a skeptic.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t try to laminate two pieces of plywood together.

Group 1 type plywood is rated for various spans. Using 1/2” plywood to span 16” will span the distance without failing, but will have too much defection. That is to say, it will be springy. It’s designed for 2 span installations. If it’s a one span situation, it will be noticeable.

Adding additional plywood layers does very little to decrease the deflection problem and if the adhesive is not installed correctly (and cured correctly) it could create other problems, like 1) bulging, 2) warping, 3) delaminating, etc.

I’d use 3/4” plywood with the wood strips you suggest. 3/4” plywood will be stiff enough that you could use in a single span situation and still be acceptable for ceramic tile floor, etc.

Also, remember to install with the face grain perpendicular to the joists. (Screw and glue...adhesive... to insure no squeaks.)

Also, this is for “subfloor” only. You still need an underlayment. Check with the manufacturer of your finish floor material to see what they require for an underlayment. (It’s different for ceramic tile, vinyl, etc.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response.  Before seeing your response, I actually tried the 'glue & screw two layers' approach (making a complete disaster of a couple sheets of plywood and a v-notched trowel trying it), and then ended up ripping them up when it didn't work out... then I smartened up and bought some 3/4" sheets and 1/8" boards and cut strips to fasten to the tops of the joists as you suggested.  Fast and easy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your plan should work just fine, assuming that the layers are bonded as you describe. I don't know that I'd bother screwing between joists, though, or maybe do so sparingly just to ensure a snug bond.

You'll want to apply the adhesive with a controlled bead (maybe 3/6" in a consistent pattern) or v-notch trowel to prevent waviness. The 3/8" layer is vulnerable to bulging due to excess adhesive.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and for the tip about bulging. I'm pretty sure I dont have v-notch trowel... would a drywall or putty knife work to smooth out the adhesive?

Comment: Nope. You need to create ridges and valleys so that the adhesive can spread and make good contact while remaining flat. You'll have a difficult time creating a flat surface with a straight trowel. They're inexpensive.

Comment: @isherwood Plywood is made from plies installed 90 degrees to one another. Adding another sheet of plywood will have two sheets running in the same direction, which could cause warping. See this.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plywood The plies are glued together using heat and pressure. “Home-made” plywood seems dangerous and could cause problems.

Comment: Won't cause warping. Will be plenty stiff. There's nothing homemade about using several layers of plywood in conjunction. It's done every time birch underlayment is added to a subfloor, with obvious benefits.

Comment: @isherwood But that’s not for structural. That’s underlayment (for floor finish) over subfloor (structural).

Comment: @lee-sam, you write that 'two sheets running in the same direction could cause warping'. This is important and news to me. Does that also apply to the next plywood (underlayment) layer? I plan to add 1/2" plywood on top of my now plywood-patched-board floor, but should I now run the 1/2" plywood underlayment the opposite direction of my plywood patches in the subfloor? In other words, should my underlayment layer of plywood run parallel to the joists since my subfloor layer runs perpendicular?

Comment: @EricHS Warping occurs when you try to glue two pieces completely together. Underlayment is not glued to the subfloor.

Comment: @EricHS Plywood is always installed perpendicular to supports.

Comment: @LeeSam Oh I see. Thanks for clarifying. I'd definetly plan my sheet placement in such a way that the edges of the underlayment would be staggered in relation to the subfloor sheets. But should I not use adhesive (in addition to flooring screws) to fasten the 1/2" plywood to the subfloor?

Comment: @EricHS I wouldn’t. Here’s a site that may help you understand why:  https://www.bestlaminate.com/blog/can-i-glue-underlayment-down-on-my-subfloor/

Comment: @LeeSam Thanks for the link. the blog mentions that I should not glue because "Underlayment is is a floating material, the same as your laminate flooring". I understand that (sort of), but now I'm questioning my fastener choice because these 1.25" flooring screws I have will lock the 1/2" plywood to the subfloor and it won't be floating at all...

Comment: @LeeSam ... So I'm thinking that the blog may not really apply to my case. I'm applying 1/2" plywood to the subfloor to raise the height of the subfloor and strengthen it in advance of using a concrete/gypsum self-leveller to deal with some serious levelness issues. In essence, I'm adding mass and height to my subfloor to get a level surface. My REAL underlayment will come after I have a level floor and will be laid on the poured floor, and THAT underlayment layer will be floating (planning to use a product called Soundeater by Impacta under solid hardwood).

Comment: @LeeSam But I'm still thinking my 1/2" plywood layer should be "glued and screwed" to give the subfloor additional strength and stability in advance of my self-leveler pour. Does this make sense? Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: @EricHS Yes, “glueing and screwing” is best. However, the term “glue and screw” refers to glueing and screwing the subfloor TO THE SUPPORTS ONLY...NOT FULL ADHESION.